# more than one character in rune literal

Tags: go

I have  a string as just `MyString` and I want to append in this data something like this:

```
MYString ("1", "a"), ("1", "b")  //END result
```

My code is something like this:

```
    query := "MyString"; 
    array := []string{"a", "b"}
    
    for i , v :=  range array{
        id := "1" 
        fmt.Println(v,i)
        query +=  '("{}", "{}"), '.format(id, v)
     }
```

but I am getting two errors:

```
./prog.go:15:23: more than one character in rune literal
./prog.go:15:39: '\u0000'.format undefined (type rune has no field or method format)
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can't use single quotes for Strings in Go. You can only use double-quotes or backticks.
Single quotes are used for single characters, called *runes*

Change your line to:

```
query +=  "(\"{}\", \"{}\"), ".format(id, v)
```

or

```
 query +=  `("{}", "{}"), `.format(id, v)
```

However, Go is not python. Go doesn't have a `format` method like that. But it has `fmt.Sprintf`.

So to really fix it, use:

```
query = fmt.Sprintf(`%s("%s", "%s"), `, query, id, v)
```

Answer (score 3):

Issue here is single quotes . Go Compiler expects a character only when encounters  '' . Rather use double quotes with escape symbol as explained in above example.